# how to execute multiple hql in 1 transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, struts

I'm trying to read the data in excel using apache poi and make some hqls and then execute them to insert to database. I want if there's any hql failed when executing then the transaction will roll back all the hqls.

Is there any way to execute multiple hqls in 1 transaction ? Any help would be great

Comment: Use batch for this: 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html

Comment: I don't get the question. A session is bound to a transaction so anything happening within the same session should be rolled back. Perhaps you have some kind of auto-commit enabled?

Comment: I think use batch is good for me.